# Insert value if value does not exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if all values in column `releases.id` exist in column `charts_extended.release_id`

If the value does not exist then I want to insert that value in column `releases.id` into column `charts_extended.release_id`

Comment: Please show your table and columns and also the query you've tried to work on too.

Comment: please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first come up with query to check whether the id exists in the table, for example:

```
SELECT id 
FROM releases
 LEFT JOIN charts_extended ON (release_id=releases.id)
WHERE release_id IS NULL;
```

If you are happy with that, you can proceed into converting it to an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO charts_extended (release_id) 
SELECT id 
FROM releases
 LEFT JOIN charts_extended ON (release_id=releases.id)
WHERE release_id IS NULL;
```